# How can I create files in my home directory without root?

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, home

I created a user, then using root I created a folder for him. The folder has the same name as the user.

When I am logged in as the user, I cannot create files or edit existing ones without using sudo. I used the command `useradd elephant` then created a password for him using `passwd elephant`.

I'm running a fresh install of Arch Linux. Is there anything obvious that I am forgetting?

Comment: Did you `chown` the folder over to the new user?

Comment: @ewhac that was the obvious sort of thing that I was looking for. Looks like I still have a bit to learn... Well, practice makes perfect. Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks a bunch! One last question, how do I mark this as solved?

Comment: You accept the correct answer by upvoting it and clicking the green arrow underneath it...

Answer (score 4):

To add a user with his home directory automatically, `adduser` is the correct command, while it creates user, home directory, allows you to set password in that moment & let you set more info about the user (full name, address, phone, etc). I recommend you to remove the user, remove the created dir and run this command of course as root.

```
# userdel 'user'
# rm -rf /home/user_dir
# adduser 'user' (follow instructions)
# ls -ltr /home
  drwxr-xr-x user user size date  user_dir
```

Or you could also change owner to your created dir

```
# chown -R user:user user_dir
```

**NOTE: -R to change all inside dirs/files owner** -R = recursive

**UPDATE:** This works specifically in Ubuntu